# Bind a service to two different app spaces in cloudfoundry

Tags: cloud-foundry, swisscomdev

Is it possible to bind a service (i.e. MariaDB) to apps in different spaces? How can I achieve it if I want to use the same database for two different spaces?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried the solution from https://docs-cloudfoundry-staging.cfapps.io/devguide/services/sharing-instances.html. 
If I run the first command I get the following error:

```
$ cf enable-feature-flag service_instance_sharing
    Server error, status code: 403, error code: 10003, message: You are not authorized to perform the requested action
```

The second command **works** and now I can see the service in the space B on the dashboard.

```
$ cf share-service SERVICE-INSTANCE -s OTHER-SPACE [-o OTHER-ORG]
```

---

Note: if I click on the service on the dashboard it says: This is a shared service. It is accessible only in the space it was shared from. The service is also shown greyed out.

Comment: Sorry the above solution is correct. Everthing above works as excepted but I have to unbind first the old database connection :-)

Answer (score 3):

Currently we don't support [service instance sharing](https://docs.cloudfoundry.org/devguide/services/sharing-instances.html). We made the necessary code changes already and tested it (Service Broker), but don't roll it out on prd because the feature is at the moment beta.

> Sharing a service instance between spaces allows apps in different
>   spaces to share databases, messaging queues, and other types of
>   services. This eliminates the need for development teams to use
>   service keys and user-provided services to bind their apps to the same
>   service instance that was provisioned using the `cf create-service`
>   command. Sharing service instances improves security, auditing, and
>   provides a more intuitive user experience.

See this [discussion](https://lists.cloudfoundry.org/g/cf-dev/topic/feedback_on_service_instance/16298067?p=,,,20,0,0,0::recentpostdate%2Fsticky,,,20,2,0,16298067) for more info when this feature will be generally available from upstream.

Comment: Until proper support is available, you can use `cf cups` and user provided services as a work around.  It's not as nice as the actual feature, but basically create one service as you normally would with `cf create-service`, create a service key, then in your second space use `cf cups` to create a user provided service with the info from your service key.  Hope that helps!

Comment: @DanielMikusa this works for MariaDB, but not for container based Services like MongoDB and Redis. Swisscom generates security groups which are space bound. MariaDB uses a global security group.

Comment: My MariaDB was created in the first space. Now I tried to create a user provided service in my second space with the credentials of the MariaDB of my first space with the following command: cf cups MariaDB_CUPS_SPACE2 -p "host, username, password, database, port". After that I bound the created MariaDB_CUPS_SPACE2 service to my app of the second space. For me this does not work but perhaps I understood something wrong?

Answer (score 0):

you can same service instance in two different spaces/orgs
follow:

1) https://docs.pivotal.io/pivotalcf/2-3/services/enable-sharing.html

2) https://docs.pivotal.io/pivotalcf/2-3/devguide/services/sharing-instances.html